# Delete Row if cell starts with certain text - Google Sheets / Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have rows of data in column A containing cells starting with AR. I would like any cell that contains AR to be deleted. I have script already but this **only deletes exact matches**

So example is AR12345 in Column A & A12345. So it should ONLY delete the cell row with AR and not just A

```
 function DeleteAny() {
 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('MULTI KIT DATA'), true);
 var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
 var values = rows.getValues();

 var rowsDeleted = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
 var row = values[i];
 // I cant put AR here because it wont delete anything. the AR numbers keep changing also
 if (row[14] == '') {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }
 }
 };
```

I have searched but cannot find anything.

Answer (score 4):

How about using javascript Array#filter ? This is probably simplest for simple data.

```
// filter values
let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  .filter(row => !row.find(v => v.match(/^AR/)))    
// clear range
sheet.getDataRange().clear()  
// write back filtered values
sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about the following modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, as a simple modification, your script is modified.

#### From:

```
 if (row[14] == '') {
```

#### To:

```
if (row[0].length > 1 && row[0].substr(0, 2) == "AR") {
```

- In this modification, the top 2 characters are retrieved with `row[0].substr(0, 2)`.
- If `AR` is included in the inner value, `if (row[0].length > 1 && row[0].includes("AR")) {` might be suitable.

#### Note:

- In your script, `row[14]` is used. But in your question, the values are in the column "A". So I used `row[0]`. If you want to check other column, please modify it.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, as other sample script, TextFinder and Sheets API are used. When you use this, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "MULTI KIT DATA"; // Please set the sheet name.
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const requests = sheet
    .getRange(`A1:A${sheet.getLastRow()}`)
    .createTextFinder("^AR")
    .matchCase(true)
    .useRegularExpression(true)
    .findAll()
    .map(r => r.getRow())
    .reverse()
    .map(r => ({deleteDimension:{range:{sheetId:sheetId,startIndex:r - 1,endIndex:r,dimension:"ROWS"}}}));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, ss.getId());
}
```

- In this sample script, the ranges of values which have `AR` at the top 2 characters are retrieved with TextFinder. And the request body is created using the retrieved ranges, and then, it requests to Sheets API with the request body. By this, the rows you want to delete are deleted.
- When there are a lot of rows you want to delete, the process cost of this sample script might be low.

### References:

- [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)
- [TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [DeleteDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#deletedimensionrequest)